# How to find the largest value of $n$ such that $S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n (2k + 1) < 68$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

Please help me solve the following:

Given the following Sigma Notation:

Given the following: $$\sum_{k=1}^n (2k+1)$$

what is the greatest number of terms for which $S_n<68$?

I tried the following:

$\sum_{k=1}^n (2k+1)$

$S_1=2(1)+1=3$

$S_2=2(2)+1=5$

$S_3=2(3)+1=7$

$t_1+t_2+t_3+ \ldots +2(k)+1=  3+5+7+...2(k)+1$

$a=3$

$d=2$

$S_n=\frac{n(2a+(n-1)d}{2}$

$68>\frac{n(2(3)+2n-2}{2}$

$34>n(4+2n)$

$17>n(2+n)$

$17>2n+n^2$

This where I get stuck, I feel like my approach is completely wrong. Please assist.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You said that you want to find the largest value of $n$ such that $S_n < 68$, but later you solved for $n$ such that $S_n > 68$.  Which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: MathJax, please.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site using MathJax.

Comment: That's correct I made a mistake on the inequality sign, Sn < 68 (Sn must be less than 68) I'm sorry for the error

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks will edit again

Comment: Don't you mean $S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n (2k + 1)$?  Also, do you want the largest $n$ such that $S_n < 68$, like it says in the problem statement, or $S_n > 68$, which is what you were calculating in the last few lines?

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^n k= 2k+1$ doesn't make sense. $k$ is a free variable on RHS but not on the left. Did you mean  $\sum_{k=1}^n k= \frac12 n (n+1)$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig That is correct $S_n= \sum_{k=1}^n (2k+1)$ and yes i want the largest n such that $S_n<68$

Comment: As it turns out, you made one key error:  You divided one side of the equation by $2$ while multiplying the other side of the equation by $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given
$$S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} (2k + 1)$$
Since we want to find the largest value of $n$ such that $S_n < 68$,
$$S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} (2k + 1) < 68$$
Since the sequence $(a_k)$ defined by $a_k = 2k + 1$ is arithmetic, this is an arithmetic series.  Hence, the $n$th partial sum is
$$S_n = \frac{n(a_1 + a_n)}{2} = \frac{n[a_1 + a_1 + (n - 1)d]}{2} = \frac{n[2a_1 + (n - 1)d]}{2}$$
Observe that $a_1 = 2 \cdot 1 + 1 = 3$ and $a_n = 2n + 1$.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
S_n & < 68\\
\frac{n(a_1 + a_n)}{2} & < 68\\
\frac{n(3 + 2n + 1)}{2} & < 68\\
\frac{n(2n + 4)}{2} & < 68\\
n(n + 2) & < 68\\
n^2 + 2n & < 68\\
n^2 + 2n + 1 & < 68 + 1 && \text{complete the square}\\
(n + 1)^2 & < 69
\end{align*}
The largest integer with square less than $69$ is $8$.  Thus, $n + 1 = 8 \implies n = 7$.

**Check:**  By direct calculation,
$$\sum_{k = 1}^7 (2k + 1) = 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 + 11 + 13 + 15 = 61 < 68$$
while
$$\sum_{k = 1}^8 (2k + 1) = 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 + 11 + 13 + 15 + 17 = 78 > 68$$
Thus, $n = 7$ is correct.

*Where did you make a mistake?*

After using the formula
$$S_n = \frac{n[2a_1 + (n - 1)d}{2}$$
to obtain
$$S_n = \frac{n(2 \cdot 3 + (n - 1) \cdot 2}{2}$$
you obtained
$$S_n = \frac{n(6 + 2n - 2)}{2}$$
Therefore, you obtained
$$\frac{n(2 \cdot 3 + 2n - 2)}{2} < 68$$
You then multiplied the expression on the left-hand side in my work by $2$ while dividing $68$ by $2$, so you were off by a factor of $4$.

You should have obtained
\begin{align*}
\frac{n(6 + 2n - 2)}{2} & < 68\\
\frac{n(2n + 4)}{2} & < 68\\
n(n + 2) & < 68
\end{align*}
and then proceeded as above.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add an observation to the answer of N. F. Taussig:
consider a square, it can be divided in the following way

[image: square divided into odd numbers]

and this proves that the sum of the first $n$ odd numbers (starting from $1$) is $n^2$. Your sum is the sum of the first $n+1$ odd numbers where you are neglecting the first (you have $n$ addends from $1$ to $n$), so it is $(n+1)^2-1$ and you have to solve $(n+1)^2<69$ in integers.